# Uniform Convergence and VC Theroy

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory, vc-dimension

I've started reading more about statistical learning theory, specifically this paper right [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444529367500161) and I cannot understand the following part:

> It turns out the conditions required to render empirical risk
>   minimization consistent involve restricting the set of admissible
>   functions. **The main insight of VC (Vapnik-Chervonenkis) theory is that
>   the consistency of empirical risk minimization is determined by the
>   worst case behavior over all functions f ∈ F that the learning machine
>   could choose**. **We will see that instead of the standard law of large
>   numbers introduced above, this worst case corresponds to a version of
>   the law of large numbers which is uniform over all functions in F**

The part that is in bold is what I do not get. This part specifically: *"Consistency of ERM is determined by the worst case behavior over all functions in function space F, that learning machine could choose"*. What is exactly meant by the **worse case behavior**? I tried looking into VC theory and could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is considered in VC theory is about the bound of error between empirical risk and real expected risk. Hence, the worst-case function is when the difference between these two risks is maximized.

Comment: Simple enough, I was thinking too much about this. Thank you.

Comment: @StefanRadonjic my pleasure.

Comment: btw, what does it mean to UNIFORMLY BOUND difference between empirical and true risk over a family of classifiers? @OmG

Comment: @StefanRadonjic means "uniform convergence" here.